# OpenCV installation

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, install-from-source

During the installation of OpenCV I get the following error:

```
moslah@moslah-Lenovo-G560:~/Downloads/opencv-2.4.10/build$ cmake ../
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.10 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.13.0-45-generic i686
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.8.2)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml video legacy objdetect photo gpu ocl nonfree contrib python stitching superres ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda java viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.23)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.40.2)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.50)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.3)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 1.6.1)
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.1)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 54.92.100)
--       format:                    YES (ver 54.63.104)
--       util:                      YES (ver 52.18.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 2.2.100)
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       video:                     YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       app:                       YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 0.10.36)
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.0.1) / libv4l2 (ver 1.0.1)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/moslah/Downloads/opencv-2.4.10/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMD FFT:                 NO
--     Use AMD BLAS:                NO
-- 
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.6)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.6)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.2)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Build Documentation:         NO
--     Sphinx:                      NO
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:           NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/moslah/Downloads/opencv-2.4.10/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/moslah/Downloads/opencv-2.4.10/build
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE** After running the suggested `sudo apt-get build-dep opencv`, the output of `cmake` is:

```
moslah@moslah-Lenovo-G560:~/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/build$ cmake ../-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:18 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
    qt5core-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:472 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:19 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Gui.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
    qt5gui-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Gui" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Gui_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Gui"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:472 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:20 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:472 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:21 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Test.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Test", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Test" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5TestConfig.cmake
    qt5test-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Test" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Test_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Test" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:472 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:22 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Concurrent.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Concurrent", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Concurrent"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt5ConcurrentConfig.cmake
    qt5concurrent-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Concurrent" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Concurrent_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Concurrent" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:472 (include)


-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- Found Sphinx 1.2.2: /usr/bin/sphinx-build
-- Found apache ant 1.9.3: /usr/bin/ant
--
-- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.10 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
--
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.13.0-45-generic i686
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.8.2)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml video legacy objdetect photo gpu ocl nonfree contrib java python stitching superres ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda viz
--
--   GUI:
--     QT 4.x:                      YES (ver 4.8.6 EDITION = OpenSource)
--     QT OpenGL support:           YES (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so)
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so)
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.50)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.3)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 1.6.1)
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.1)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 54.92.100)
--       format:                    YES (ver 54.63.104)
--       util:                      YES (ver 52.18.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 2.2.100)
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 1.2.4)
--       video:                     YES (ver 1.2.4)
--       app:                       YES (ver 1.2.4)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 1.2.4)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.2.4)
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.0.1) / libv4l2 (ver 1.0.1)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.0)
--     Use TBB:                     YES (ver 4.2 interface 7000)
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/moslah/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMD FFT:                 NO
--     Use AMD BLAS:                NO
--
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.6)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.6)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.2)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
--
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.3)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java tests:                  YES
--
--   Documentation:
--     Build Documentation:         YES
--     Sphinx:                      /usr/bin/sphinx-build (ver 1.2.2)
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/bin/pdflatex
--
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
--
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
--
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/moslah/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/moslah/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/build
moslah@moslah-Lenovo-G560:~/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/build$
```

Answer (score 5):

[Opencv](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/opencv) requires a lot of dependencies to be built from sources. The easy way would be to install all the build dependencies using this command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep opencv
```

And restart the `cmake` configuration.

Comment: and how can i restart the cmake configuration?

Comment: Just type `cmake ../` as you did during your first attempt.

Comment: moslah@moslah-Lenovo-G560:~/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/build$ sudo apt-get build-dep opencv
[sudo] password for moslah: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

Comment: i think i have 4 package not upgraded

Comment: when i have restarted the cmake commande. i have had this https://drive.google.com/open?id=14cY2laxIDCmBgWixUviuiY3omGMI3vbbgAJMIVz9PkA&authuser=0

Comment: Hi @OussemaMoslah that output looks like it worked.  Once cmake is complete, the next step is to run `make`, then `sudo make install`.  See step 3 in the installation instructions http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation

Comment: E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
Got this error while installing on raspberry pi :/

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya: Try to enable universe (see [How do I enable the “Universe” repository?](http://askubuntu.com/q/148638/32239))

Answer (score 0):

I use this list to meet the dependencies for opencv --

```
libopencv-dev build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config 
python-dev python-numpy libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libjpeg-dev  
libpng12-dev libtiff4-dev libjasper-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev 
libswscale-dev libxine-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev 
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libv4l-dev libtbb-dev libqt4-dev 
libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev 
libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev x264 v4l-utils unzip
```

If you want to get a more detailed instructions, I have curated one for myself, here it is --

https://github.com/chudur-budur/opencv#notes-from-chudur-budur

Comment: Please avoid `apt-get -y` when proposing package installation, so that people can evaluate what is being installed.

Comment: @Avio I have mistakenly put the `apt-get` part, I meant to just put the list.